# Is it possible to use the create method from within one class to insert into another class table in OpenERP?

Tags: python, class, odoo

I have a `class student` and my idea is that each time the class gets called I need to insert some data into another table, lets call it `logs` which is `class logs` and has its own `logs` table

The problem is that when I call

```
logs.create(cr, uid, i, context)
```

Inside the `class student`, OpenERP will give me back the error:

```
unbound method create() must be called with logs instance as first argument (got Cursor instance instead)
```

I tried changing the `cr` with `logs` but it will keep giving me a similar error.

Is is possible to insert records in a table created by another class from within a given class?

Any tip or module with this functionalities will be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

**EDIT:** I am realising that maybe I can call

```
cr.execute()
```

With an `INSERT INTO` statement from within my `students class`, but I am not sure this is the *appropriate* way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `logs` is a class deriving from `orm.Model` (or `osv.osv`) then you need to get the model object from the pool of models, and then you can use the `create` method:

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields
class logs(orm.Model):
    _name = 'logs'
    _columns = {'name': fields.char('Name', ...),
                'message': fields.char('Message', ...),
               }
    # ...

class student(orm.Model):
    _name = 'student'
    _columns = {...}
    def some_method(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        # get the logs model
        logs_obj = self.pool.get('logs')
        # prepare the value dict for new entry
        values = {'name': val_of_the_name_col,
                  'message':  val_of_the_message_col,
                  }
        # call create
        log_id = logs_obj.create(cr, uid, value, context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am learning and I was not aware of `pool.get` This really help, thanks a lot.